# How to retrieve html text from stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, html, stored-procedures

I have a multi line text in html format stored in database like this:

```
@"<font  size='1'>  <p><span ...='25' width='120' src='http://www.mysite.com/Images/new-site-logo.jpg'/></span></p>  <h2 ...</table></font>"
```

and I have a stored procedure to retrieve this from database.

In C# I call the stored procedure in `myclass.cs` like this:

```
public string GetEhtmlContent(int id)
{
    ...
    SqlParameter HTMLParam = new SqlParameter("@HtmlEmail","");
    HTMLParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(HTMLParam);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    htmlContent = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HTMLParam.Value);
    ...
}
```

It gets id as input parameter and it should give the html as output but all I get is "@" which is the first character in `HTMLParam.value`.

Can anybody help me how I should get all the html context in my HTMLParam?

Thanks in advance,
Mona

Comment: well lets see the `.CommandText` property value as well as the text of the stored proc.

Comment: should work just fine, but you do not have to enclose the string in @".." quotes in the db; unless you have some specific need, I would expect the first character to be '<'

Comment: to clarify, I support Boo's request for more info. In addition to what he asks, I would like to know where it is you "get the @", in HTMLParam.Value, in htmlContent or further down the stream (in which case I would like to see all manipulations)

Answer (score 1):

What does your parameter list on the stored procedure in T-SQL look like??

Allow me a guess - you probably have something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourHtmlRetrievelProc    
   ...
   @HtmlEmail VARCHAR OUTUPT
```

or something like that.

Any `varchar` that's defined as a parameter **without** specifying a length defaults to **1 character in length** - that's most likely why you're only getting back 1 character....

You need to specify a length:

```
@HtmlEmail VARCHAR(2000) OUTUPT
```

or even:

```
@HtmlEmail VARCHAR(MAX) OUTUPT
```

For the same reason, I would also change your C# code from:

```
SqlParameter HTMLParam = new SqlParameter("@HtmlEmail","");
```

to:

```
SqlParameter HTMLParam = new SqlParameter("@HtmlEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2000);
```

You need to make sure to use the same length as defined in the stored procedure header. Use `Int.MaxValue` if you're defined `VARCHAR(MAX)` as parameter in T-SQL

Comment: Thanks. I aded this:sqlDbType ,2000" as you said and it works:)

Comment: @user1110863: GREAT! So now that it works - please show your gratitude by **accepting** the answer provided. It's the right and polite thing to do on StackOverflow and serves as an incentive for others to continue to help those looking for answers. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)

Answer (score 0):

use `HTMLParam.Size` to specify the size of parameter value